# youtube api to comment on a video in nodejs

Tags: node.js, youtube-api

I am using googleapis npm module to comment on  a video on youtube .Going through the documentation i have written the following code ...

```
service.commentThreads.insert({
   auth: auth,
   part: 'snippet',
   body: {
    "snippet": {
      "channelId": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
      "topLevelComment": {
       "snippet": {
        "textOriginal": "This video is awesome!"
       }
      },
      "videoId": "MILSirUni5E"
     }
  }

    });
```

I would like a nodejs specific answer am i doing something wrong . The documentation asks for a request body which i think is right or is it  supposed to be defined that way

Comment: Can you share any error logs?

Comment: the question was answered but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the function doesn't receive a property known as body. I had success on naming it resource..